# Passport.js authentication load client id an secret from config file

Tags: express, sails.js

My application is built in sails.js framework

Here is my passport authentication file located in `config/passport.js`

also my configuration is stored in `config/local.js` file

```
module.exports = {

 google:{
      clientId:'XXX',
      secret:'XX',
      callbackurl:'XXXX'
  }

}
```

in passport.js file

```
var sails            = require('sails');

passport.use('google',new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID:sails.config.google.clientId,
        clientSecret:sails.config.google.secret,
        callbackURL:sails.config.google.callbackurl
    },function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log('result here');
});
```

but i got

***Details:TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined***

Comment: Try using global `sails` object instead of `require('sails')`.

Comment: how can you give an example??

Comment: Just remove this `var sails            = require('sails');` line